# How to force nuget to take latest build of a package?

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-restore

I have a problem with nuget getting the first build of a specifik assembly version, not the latest build. Here are steps that explain what is going on:

1. Removing local nuget cache.
2. Delete project.lock.json files in project.
3. Checking build number for latest build in nuget feed: 102
4. Run dotnet restore --no-cache.
5. The project folder is recreated in local cache, but with build number 98.

Both build 98 and 102 have version number 1.2. How can I force dotnet restore to take the latest build of the nuget package without increasing the version number to 1.3?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using floating versions (aka versions with asterisks)? Can you share your project.json or csproj file?

Comment: Could be cache location that you have not cleaned: http://lastexitcode.com/projects/NuGet/FileLocations/ or nuget scratch folder: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/802

Answer (score 16):

Clear **all** NuGet caches with command
`dotnet nuget locals all --clear`

Then NuGet takes the latest version of the package from the feed.

Comment: It will work only on developer's computer. You cant do it in build server, because it may affect other builds.

Answer (score 3):

Follow [the answer by Jiří Kyzlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45927211/45311) to clear your NuGet cache.

Then follow with a `dotnet add ProjectName package PackageName` to basically re-add the package and update the **versioned** reference in the project file.

`dotnet restore` restores references from the project file. Solely clearing the cache doesn't change your project reference.

Comment: Actually the cache clearing wasn't necessary. Just calling `dotnet add` again made it install the latest package.